# Is $3(2k+1)(2^{2k+1}-1)>(2^{k+3}-1)(2^{k+1}-1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $k$ be an integer. I need to prove that:
 $$3(2k+1)(2^{2k+1}-1)>(2^{k+3}-1)(2^{k+2}-1)$$
where $k>a$ for a suitable $a$.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean weak inequality:  at $k=2$ both are $31\cdot 15$.

Comment: In fact I meant strong inequality, let $k>a$ for a suitable $a$.

Comment: I tried an inductive argument but I could not prove...

Comment: If you mean $k>a$ for suitable $a$, then please edit the question so it says that.

Comment: The leading term on the left side is $12k\times2^{2k}$, on the right side, $32\times2^{2k}$, so it's clear the left side is bigger once $k$ is big enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $k\geq 1$ we have:
$$(2^{k+3}-1)(2^{k+2}-1)=2^{2k+5}-3\cdot 2^{k+2}+1\leq16(2^{2k+1}-1)$$
and for any $k\geq 3$ we have:
$$3(2k+1)\geq 16,$$
hence we have to check only the cases $k=1,2$.

Answer (score 2):

The right side simplifies to $6 \times 2^k + 1$. Replacing $x = 2^k$ means the equation is $3(2k+1)(2x^2-1) > 6x + 1$.

$2x^2-1 > 6x + 1$ for $x \ge 4$, so checking cases from here is sufficient